# Use different class templates inside another class template

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following pointers class templates :

```cpp
// PointerTemplates.hpp    

template <class T, class X = ClassX<T>, class Y = ClassY<T> >
class Smart_Ptr_A
{
    // [...]
};

template <class T>
class Smart_Ptr_B
{
    // [...]
};

template <class T, class Count = TSCount>
class Smart_Ptr_C
{
    // [...]
};
```

I want to create other smart pointers that correspond to those pointers but where the member pointer isn't the object inside "<>", but act as it was.
Something like:

```cpp
template<class PointedClass>
class Smart_Ptr_A_Modified
{
public:
    // [...]
    PointedClass& operator*() const
    { return m_pOtherClass->getPointedClass(); }

    // OtherClass contains a PointedClass.
    Smart_Ptr_A<OtherClass> m_pOtherClass;
};
```

Almost all methods and operator of the smart pointers are the same, so I want to use a template to implements the things they have in common and specialize them.
**How could I do that ?**

For now, I have something like the following:

```cpp
// Common implementation
template< template<class> class PtrType, class PointedClass>
class CommonModifiedPtr
{
    // implementation of things in common 
    // [...]

private:
    PtrType<OtherClass> m_pOtherClass;
}

// Specialization

template<class PointedClass>
class Smart_Ptr_A_Modified
  : CommonModifiedPtr<Smart_Ptr_A<OtherClass>, PointedClass>
{
public:

  PointedClass* releaseControl()
  { return m_pOtherClass->releaseControl(); }
};

template<class PointedClass>
class Smart_Ptr_B_Modified
  : CommonModifiedPtr<Smart_Ptr_B<OtherClass>, PointedClass>
{};

template<class PointedClass>
class Smart_Ptr_C_Modified
  : CommonModifiedPtr<Smart_Ptr_C<OtherClass>, PointedClass>
{};
```

But I get the following error for each of the specialization:

> error C3200: 'Smart_Ptr_A_Modified' : invalid template argument for template parameter 'PtrType', expected a class template

Additional information : I use MSVC++ 10.0 with C++98 and I only have little knowledge of templates.

Comment: C++98? That's too old. Honestly, you'd better abandon this project and move to C++11/14/17 and just use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Can't do. My enterprise is still using C++98 and it's not going to change soon.

Comment: There are probably C++98 compatible libraries implementing smart pointers, which would save your employer the time and technical debt of rolling the millionth variation thereof.

Comment: We already have smart pointers 100% functionnal used in all our code.
What I want is to use those smart pointers in composition for other "kind of" smart pointers that would do other things that handling a pointer.
It would be nice to have a common interface for the pointer to override, but there isn't one and I will not risk the modification of the implementation (used in all our projects) to only implement the thing above.

Comment: So anyway, using a more recent C++ version wouldn't change much (at least for the smart pointers, maybe some templates improvements would help more recent versions).

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is indeed the correct approach.
In the following code:

```
template<class PointedClass>
class Smart_Ptr_X_Modified
  : CommonModifiedPtr<Smart_Ptr_X<OtherClass>, PointedClass>
{ // ...
```

Should be replaced with:

```
template<class PointedClass>
class Smart_Ptr_X_Modified
  : CommonModifiedPtr<Smart_Ptr_X, PointedClass>
{ // ...
```

With 'X' replaced by A,B,C respectively.
This is because `Smart_Ptr_X<OtherClass>` is a specific class and not a class template.

---

Edit: The above might not be exactly what you want. This depends on what `OtherClass` is and how you want it to fit into your code.
For a better answer, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

---

Second edit: After the replacement above, the problem you encounter derives from the optional template arguments - The `Smart_Ptr_X` classes expect different template parameters (never mind that some of them have default values), and handling them uniformly will be problematic.

One ugly solution I can suggest, is that for purposes of `CommonModifiedPtr` you do not use `Smart_Ptr_X`, and instead use something like:

```
template <class T>
class Simple_Smart_Ptr_X : Smart_Ptr_X<T> {};
```

Comment: Thanks. After replacement : "error C3201: the template parameter list for class template 'Smart_Ptr_*' does not match the template parameter list for template parameter 'PtrType'".
Also, I don't know if it's the information missing for `OtherClass`, but it's a pretty basic class, i.e. **not** a class template **nor** an abstract class.

Comment: This is a somewhat more complicated problem. See second edit.

Comment: Your first response may have helped me to find something. At least it compiles, I'll keep updating.
I first declare a template<class T>
class SmartPtrA : Smart_Ptr_A<T> {};
Then I use that in the specialization because it's a class template and not a specific class.

Comment: I've given up, I've just created a class for each smart pointer. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers